# Import existing histogram into R

Tags: r

I already analysed a huge data set using ROOT and saved a histogram in a text file in the form "(double) bin position" "(int) bin value".
E.g.:

```
0.1 0
0.2 1
0.3 4
0.4 2
0.5 1
...
```

I have imported the txt file into R and have now two vectors. So far I cannot find a function in R allowing to import an already existing histogram. Such a function should allow to set the bin position and the bin values (=frequencies) of individual bins of a histogram. It would be nice if you could help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try barplot (probably the easiest way).

Or have a look at the code in `hist`:

```
# ....
r <- structure(list(breaks = breaks, counts = counts, density = dens, 
    mids = mids, xname = xname, equidist = equidist), class = "histogram")
if (plot) {
    plot(r, freq = freq1, col = col, border = border, angle = angle, 
        density = density, main = main, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, 
        xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, axes = axes, labels = labels, 
        ...)
# ....
```

So make up a structure like the `r` above, assign it the class "histogram" and just use `plot` with it. Or if you don't like to assign it a class, use `graphics:::plot.histogram`.

Comment: Thanks alot! Works out perfectly, as I wanted to have it:)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
x <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
y <- c(0, 1, 4, 2, 1, 0, 3)

library(MASS)
truehist(rep(x,y), prob = F, h = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: you forgot to add `library(MASS)`